# snap_cursor_to_selected with context is incorrect

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to snap the 3D-cusor to an object. After that I would like to copy another object to the position of the 3D-cursor. The code is as follow:

Code sample:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(ctx)
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
        obj.select = False
        new_obj.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = new_obj
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False)
        break
```

**Python error is:**

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Modified code sample:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(ctx)
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected(ctx, use_offset=False)
        obj.select = False
        new_obj.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = new_obj
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False)
        break
```

**Python message:**

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "use_offset" unrecognized
```

I use Blender 2.77a. What can I do? Many thanks for our help.

Comment: related : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add?lq=1

Comment: please edit your original post to add info

Comment: override all operators :  `snap_cursor_to_selected(ctx)` and so on

Comment: I do that. But I receive the same error message.

Comment: did you did this `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(ctx, use_offset=False) `also ?

Comment: I try it. Python send me this: TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "use_offset" unrecognized

Comment: you shouldn't get this error can you update the question

Comment: there is another problem though the copied context doesn't update the active object ( it will be outdated after changing the active object )

Comment: there is no `use_offset` in   `snap_cursor_to_selected` that's your mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override all operators that depends on context as follows :

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(ctx)
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected(ctx)
        obj.select = False
        new_obj.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = new_obj

        # take new copy of the context because it is outdated now
        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]            

        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(ctx, use_offset=False)
        break
```

Comment: great, it works. Many many thanks for this support.

Comment: What does the -1 do please?

Comment: @Gary it gets the last element in an array

Answer (score 0):

You can move the cursor without using operators, then you don't have to get the context right.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        break

for space in area.spaces:
    if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        break

space.cursor_location = bpy.context.active_object.location
```

But then your snapping the cursor to an object, then snapping another object to the cursor, you can bypass the cursor and just set the new objects location.

```
new_obj.location = old_obj.location
```